# Complex analysis Limit

Tags: complex-analysis, limits

Find
$$\lim_{z \to 1+i} \frac {z^{2} -4z+4+2i}{z^{2}-2z+2}$$

Hi guys, I am now into complex analysis topics, and I have encounter a problem with this limit,

What I have tried is to substitite $z=1+i$ to the equation, and I got the answer

$$\frac{i^{2}+1}{1+i+i^{2}}$$

probably, this is wrong, and I think this question is related to the $\epsilon$ or $\delta$, what should I do to get the correct answer of the limit?

Thank you.

Comment: I don't say this is wrong/right, but $i^2+1=0$, so your answer is also equal to $0$.

Comment: ＠Mahdi Oh, I juz realize that haha, my mind was blocked, but juz not sure if this is the proper way to solve the limit～

Comment: Note that $z^2-2z+2$ for $z=1+i$ is zero.

Comment: Factorize both the numerator and denominator.

Comment: Make the denominator real by multiplying it with its complex conjugate.

Comment: Why not L'Hopital, by the way ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**: If you plug in correctly for both the top and the bottom and then simplify you will get an indeterminate limit of $\frac{0}{0}$. Since both the top and the bottom are just complex polynomials this tells you that $1+i$ is their root. What would you do with a real valued limit if you had a fraction of two polynomials that share a root?